# Some more tag maintenance

Tags: discussion, status-completed

These can (and should) probably be nuked:

[oddities](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/oddities), [down](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/down), [up](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/up), [free-hosting](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/free-hosting), [cheap-hosting](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cheap-hosting), [what-is](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/what-is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done [oddities](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/oddities), [down](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/down) and [up](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/up)

Answer (score 1):

[free-hosting](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/free-hosting) is gone.

**Edit**: 
[cheap-hosting](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cheap-hosting) and [what-is](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/what-is) are also gone.